# Why is there a white dot in the notification tray?

Tags: notification

[image: Desktop]
[image: Desktop2]

In the notification tray, top right, there is a white dot.
Why?
It is only there when the screen is unlocked,
and it will sometimes disappear after a while.
I hadn't installed any app recently when it started.

Comment: I think it might be an application at the start or a GNOME extension. You can verify with "Startup Applications" and gnome-tweaks.

Comment: Can you please use a smaller image and also highlight the "point" you are talking about?

Comment: Done. The white dot is pointed at by a arrow.

Comment: Moving the cursor over doesn't give you any notification?

Comment: Have you tried a uniform one color background ? Just to rule out the possibility it is the desktop background....

Comment: Yes I have. It is definitely not the background, as it moves around sometimes in the notification tray if I close Discord and then open Discord again, for instance, it will move to the right. I added another screenshot to clarify it is not the background. And no, it doesn't give me any notification if I move the mouse over it.

Comment: So, what's the problem?